# Mac illustrator shortcuts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mac

Hi i just swapped from a pc to a mac and feel a bit lost cause I cant find many of the shortcuts i was getting used to.

-I can't scale an object uniform just by clicking on its bounding box and shift+dragging in/out.

-I can't duplicate an object by alt+clicking and dragging

How should I do that?should I edit the shortcuts preferences?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me as Alt and Shift keys work on Mac just like they do on PC. Try quitting all programs including illustrator and then restart illustrator only and see if this problem persists.

Comment: nothing is changed

Comment: Just to be sure, did you close _all_ the applications? Quick googling tells me that closing applications, updating mac, updating illustrator, and restarting computer or trashing illustrator settings might help

Comment: What version of Illustrator? What Mac OS? What Mac model? The modifier keys you site should work EXACTLY as you expect them to. You've got some other issue causing problems.

Comment: Software compatibility test -- Restart the Mac. Launch ONLY illustrator - try the modifiers. Do they work?

Comment: I didn't close Chrome now I close it and reopen it and the problem is solved! thanks

Comment: Hah. I just knew it cause you replied my first comment quite fast. Well, it's good that it works now.

Comment: @Lollero, how about making your comment an answer so it can be accepted and the question shown as answered? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a bug.

Alt and Shift *normally* work in Illustrator just like they do on PC.

---

The one that seemed to work was:

**Closing *all* open applications and then running illustrator again.**

( People have reported that closing a single application might help ( Often a web browser ), but to be on the safe side closing all open applications is better. )

---

Other possible fixes are:

- Updating Mac.
- Updating Illustrator.
- Trashing Illustrator settings.
- Restarting computer.

Comment: Known Mac issue is a conflict between older versions of Intuit (Quicken) and Microsoft (Entourage) applications as well as some VPN software - just to name a couple. They seem to commandeer shortcut keys and refuse to release them. Updating Intuit and Microsoft Apps to their lastest release may also cure the issue.

Comment: @Scott ...and that's not even bad considering that I've once tested coding program that was reserving/blocking keys for itself for other uses, keys that would normally let you write pretty common symbols like `$ {} #` and so on. Only way to get past that was to get a plugin that allowed setting hotkeys :/

Comment: @Lollero there?

Comment: please come here for a while: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner